# Linking to Stylesheet from Javascript Asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using wysihtml5, a jQuery WYSIWYG text editor, inside of my Rails app. The wysihtml5 js files are located my vendor directory.

When initializing the wysihtml5 editor, you can pass a link to a stylesheet that the editor will use, for example:

```
initWysihtml5 = (id, toolbar) ->
  editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(id, stylesheets: ['wysihtml5-style.css'])
```

My question, in Rails is how do I reference stylesheets in the javascript? I am including it in my layout like so: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "wysihtml5-style", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` but the issue is, I don't know how to link to the stylesheet when the path is dynamically generated with the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix your coffescript file with `.erb` and then you can use view helpers for this. You don't have to worry about performance of the extra erb parsing becouse i guess you will precompile your assets in production.

ex:

```
# somefile.js.coffee.erb
initWysihtml5 = (id, toolbar) ->
  editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(id, stylesheets: ['<%= asset_path("wysihtml5-style.css") %>'])
```